# Clock time indicator display on center top of screen sometimes shows outdated times for a few moments Ubuntu 20.10 due to graphics issue

Tags: clock

This is a 20.10 regression that did not happen in 20.04. It is a graphics problem, not about setting the actual time.

Sometimes if I leave my computer idle, when I come back to it the clock is out of date.

Or sometimes it shows two digits superimposed one on top of the other. This strongly indicates that it is a graphics issue.

Then if I start messing with windows/clicking around it soon updates to the correct current result.

This can be very misleading, and lead to being late for an appointment.

Is there a bug report/fix on the way, and if not what's the best place to report it?

Lenovo ThinkPad P51, NVIDIA Quadro M1200 GPU, NVIDIA driver version 460.32.03.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search gave me this web site. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Hi David, I was asking more specifically about what's the correct Launchpad tracker: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu which is the more likely location to have effect.